# Does CvQuadEdge2D have an equivalent in OpenCV 3

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.2 with Netbeans 8.0 on Ubuntu 16(LTS).

CvQuadEdge2D was quite useful in OpenCV 2 but appears to be gone from OpenCV 3.  The closest I could find was

```
struct CV_EXPORTS QuadEdge
{
    QuadEdge();
    QuadEdge(int edgeidx);
    bool isfree() const;

    int next[4];
    int pt[4];
};
```

in imageproc.hpp.  However

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

int main(){
    struct CV_EXPORTS QuadEdge* edge
}
```

results in QuadEdge being "undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenCV 3 the concept behind [`CvQuadEdge2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/legacy/doc/planar_subdivisions.html#cvquadedge2d) is in [`Edge`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html#af73f08576709bad7a36f8f8e5fc43c84).

Now you can navigate through edges using [`getEdge`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html#af73f08576709bad7a36f8f8e5fc43c84). You can get the list of the vertices of all edges using [`getEdgeList`](http://docs.opencv.org/master/df/dbf/classcv_1_1Subdiv2D.html#ab527c11e9938eed53cf9c790afa9416d)

---

`QuadEdge` itself is a protected member of the class `Subdiv2d`, so you cannot access it. You should use the *new* `Edge` interface.